# Simple Python HTTP server with caching proxy for some routes

Tags: python, http, proxy, python-3.x

I like to develop a simple HTTP in Python3 which basically should support 3 different behaviors:

- Load local files by their relative path to the root folder e.g. myhost/static/index.html
- Mirror remote URL and map them to local urls e.g. myhost/google/* => google.com/* (with HTTP/HTTPS, header support and optional local caching)
- Support dynamic results on specific routes e.g. myhost/javascript/mymodule.js (compresses mymodule.js via e.g. Uglify and returns the result)

Thinking about using Tornado or CheeryPy but no luck yet regarding what's the easiest way to implement the proxy part without doing it all on my own.

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe some combination of the requests library and Tornado/CheeryPy?